# Почему в БД попадают записи на 2 часа меньше?

Tags: php, mysql

Записываю данные:

```
'date_add' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

но они почему-то становятся на 2 часа меньше системного времени.

http://joxi.net/52ak6QKhEGYMpr

Как сделать, чтобы дата заходила корректная?

Comment: Скорее всего дело во временных зонах. `date` может выводить время в вашем текущем часовом поясе, а в БД сохранятся время в `timestamp'e`
Для точного ответа не хватает информации в вашем вопросе

Comment: готов предоставить, какая информация нужна?

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Moscow');
```

Данный код установит таймзон для Москвы.

Таким же способом можно указать другой регион.

После выставлении региона, функция `date` будет выводить корректную дату со временем.

Comment: где разместить этот код?

Comment: в начало скрипта

Comment: поставил в index.php, ничего не поменялось

Comment: получилось так: current_time('mysql', 0)

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю нужно проверить настройки часового пояса:

1) Перейдите на страницу phpinfo () и найдите загруженный файл конфигурации и откройте файл php.ini, указанный в этом разделе.

2) Измените настройки часового пояса по умолчанию, добавив новый часовой пояс, изменив эту строку: date.timezone = Europe/Moscow.
Список поддерживаемых временных зон в документации [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php)

3) Сохраните файл php.ini и перезапустите сервис, если Apache.